# How to find the Employee deductions, Additions items from QuickBooks Desktop by c#?

Tags: c#, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbfc

For exporting employee timecard data into QuickBooks we can check the Earning items through the following c# code by using QBFC (Using 8.0)

```
QBFC8Lib.IEarnings earnings40 = null;
string ItemName = "Example_EarnType";
if(employeeRet.EmployeePayrollInfo.OREarnings != null)
    count = employeeRet.EmployeePayrollInfo.OREarnings.EarningsList.Count; 
if(count > 0)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= count - 1; j++) 
    { 
        earnings40 = employeeRet.EmployeePayrollInfo.OREarnings.EarningsList.GetAt(j); 
        if(earnings40.PayrollItemWageRef.FullName.GetValue().ToLower() == itemname.ToLower())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

By using above code we can find the Employees Earning items easily.
But How can we check the items that is in Additions/Deductions and map to them by c#?

Screenshot of QB UI view

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is not available through the QBXML SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So that means we cannot able to get the deduction  item list through integrated applications. right ? is there any alternative way that you know !